# Excel find closest bigger value in a column to a given lookup value

Tags: excel

I am going to input data in A2:A100. Based on a formula, a calculation is made and returns results in J2:J100. The lookup value is in cell P2. There are cells in column J that are currently displaying "#DIV/0!", due to the fact that there are cells in column A that have not been filled yet.

I am trying to find the closest bigger value in A2:A100, using as lookup value P2. I input in Q2 the following array formula (ctrl+shift+enter): =LARGE(J2:J100;COUNTIF(J2:J100;">"&$P$2)) This formula returns "#DIV/0!". I assume that cells in column J that are currently displaying "#DIV/0!" are the cause of the problem.

Could anyone please help me to get excel to ignore these cells in column J and find the closest bigger value in regards to the lookup value in P2?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you put IFERROR( , 0) in column J so have 0? Or is it important not to have false zeroes?

Comment: It is kind of important not to have false zeroes in column J, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: This is an off topic question..

Comment: I wouldn't say it was off-topic, although would have been better if illustrated with some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it with AGGREGATE, using the option to ignore error values

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,J2:J100,COUNTIF(J2:J100,">"&$P$2))
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you very much for your time and i am sincerely sorry for posting an off topic question.

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't agree with the user who suggested it was off-topic BTW.

Comment: You could also use this version `=AGGREGATE(15,6,J2:J100/(J2:J100>$P$2),1)`